# If videogames do not conserve momentum, must that mean that they do not have translational symmetry?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry

I've heard said many times that symmetries in our universe imply the existence of conserved quantities. One example often given is that translational symmetry implies that momentum is conserved.

This seems to imply that a universe where momentum is not conserved (e.g. strafe jumping, booster pads) cannot possibly be translationally symetric. Is this correct? And how does this manifest itself in the specific case of videogame worlds?

Comment: Video games do not obey the universe's laws of physics. They just do what they are programmed to do.

Comment: @Jon Custer I was expecting such a remark. If you believe that videogames do not obey the specific law I refer to, that symetry implies conserved quantities, please post that as an answer, and explain why it is even called a law then. If you believe that the law that symetry implies conservation is not a physical law, but a mathematical one, then I will move this question to math exchange.

Comment: Again, physical laws have nothing to do with how video games work. I can program a video game to execute 'physics' with a random number generator. Why would you expect to use physical laws on an unphysical thing?

Comment: Then why is there a law that states that you can only have translational symetry if you have momentum conservation? If videogames can break this law, that statement would simply be false. We are not talking about a law that says "momentum is conserved" that is a law describing our specific universe, we are talking about a law that states "any universe that has translational symetry conserves momentum" and videogames seem to have translational symetry but not conserve momentum, in clear violation of this law which supposedly should be true in any theoretical system of physics that coulde exist.

Comment: To keep things as simple as possible, videogames obey all the laws of physics. The problem is what human brain perceives as a _human_ character, a _block_ or a solid object, for videogames they are sets of zeroes and ones and for your monitor, sets of instructions that tell which emitter will emit what color of light and where. You definite the laws of physics of a videogame yourself using the laws of physics of your world. For example, a moving block in videogame is actually a matrix that changes its numerical values. You define how the values change, hence you define laws that govern it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question (v1) because it appears to be about video games rather than physical systems.

Comment: @JonCuster, OP is not asking a question about video games. OP is asking a question about physics. OP mentioned a video game because the game _can_ be programmed to  obey laws (including realistic physical laws, if that's what floats your boat.) I'm not sure I quite understand what "has translational symmetry" means, but OP is asking whether programming the game to have that feature _implies_ that it must also have a feature that is isomorphic to "conservation of momentum."

Comment: @SolomonSlow - a game can also be programmed to have entirely non-physical laws. You can program it to do almost anything. Since translation symmetry and momentum conservation is an outcome of our particular universe happens to work, there is no requirement that a Fortran/C/Python/whatever program cares at all about that.

Comment: @JonCuster, Yeah, well, you've heard my opinion, and I've heard yours, and somehow, I doubt that the OP is ever going to come back and tell either one of us what the question really was about.

Comment: There's little point in further discussion. The question has been closed, doublefelix has given a good answer so I don't care to challange that, everyone should be satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usually-unstated premise for "translational symmetry implies momentum conservation" is that the laws of physics of the system in question follow the Euler-Lagrange equation of motion coming from some translation-invariant Lagrangian. Since a video game universe is not constrained to follow *any* equations of motion, there is no requirement that translational symmetry be related to momentum conservation.

I think it's an interesting question actually, since it exposes the fact that "translational symmetry implies momentum conservation" is not a completely universal statement.

Answer (score 4):

The full statement of Noether's theorem, as applied to momentum, is

> Lagrangian systems with translational symmetry have a conserved quantity (which we call momentum).

If the physics engine in a video game produces motion which does not conserve momentum, then it follows that

- either the dynamics cannot be framed as a Lagrangian system,
- or it is not translationally invariant.

The specific variant will obviously depend on the details.

Answer (score 1):

The connection between conservation of momentum and translational symmetry (i.e., Noether's theorem) requires the system under consideration to obey an action principle.  In general, video game physics does not work this way;  rather, video game physics simulate motion via some version of Newton's Laws, with the possibility to apply external time-dependent forces (i.e., running) and with dissipative forces included (i.e., friction.)   Generally speaking, time-dependent and dissipative forces do not admit a Lagrangian formulation, and so the connection between conserved quantities and symmetries is broken.